# indexof on 64 vs 32 bit pc

Tags: c#, 32-bit, int32

i'm using the line below to find a position of the test withing HTML document and it works fine on a 64bit machine but does not work on my 32bit Windows 2008 server.

IntStart1 variable returns 2 on 64bit and 0000029ae on 32 bit. please help.

```
Int32 intStart1 = strHtmlText.IndexOf("<TABLE class=");
```

Comment: What is the value of strHtmlText in both cases?

Comment: Minor aside, it is more idiomatic to use `int` rather than `Int32` here.

Comment: Have you inspected and verified that `strHtmlText` contains the string ""<TABLE class=" at position 2 on your 32 bit platform ?

Comment: hi David, it's the same. see below. i'm still puzzeled as to why a hexidecimal number returned   <FORM name=fViewForm action=OrderItemAdd method=post><INPUT type=hidden value=CatalogModelSelection name=reserverd_prevUrl> <INPUT type=hidden value=CatalogSKUSelection name=reserverd_url> <INPUT type=hidden value=CatalogSKUSelectionPage name=reserverd_viewname> <INPUT type=hidden value=10001 name=storeId> <INPUT type=hidden value=-1 name=langId> 
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=763 bgColor=#1b3067 border=0>
<TBODY>

Comment: That text does not contain the string you are searching for.

Answer (score 4):

`String.IndexOf()` is one of the most widely used functions in existence. I'd be simply astounded if it did not work.

The most likely explanation is that you have different values for `strHtmlText`. Inspect the values of that string and I'm sure you will see what is going on.